# How to install xbox 360 "whserver"?

Tags: xbox-360

It has been almost a year since I last played on my Xbox, and I want to start viewing some WMV files on it through Windows Home Server. When I tried to play a WMV file it says I need a media update. According to a few websites, I need to get an Xbox live silver or gold account and download the optional media update. I did just that and did a general system update. However, after that I was still unable to play my WMV files. How can I get my Xbox 360 to download this Optional Media Update? I'm trying to play some files from http://microsoftpdc.com/Videos which looks to me in HD content.

Comment: I think this is offtopic on this website. This is a gaming site, so your question should be related to gaming and any issues you encountering while playing games. I suggest you post this question on superuser.com

Comment: http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Optional-Media-Update/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802fffe07df

Comment: @JamesJiao, this is an on-topic question, see [this thread on meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96/non-gaming-gaming-console-questions-allowed)

Comment: Interesting, agent, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

To install the optional media update, go to the [page on xbox.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59850/how-to-install-xbox-360-whserver) describing the update. On that page there is a button to download the update to your Xbox 360.

Answer (score 0):

If the Xbox 360 has trouble viewing a video, it will prompt you to install the optional media update to try to resolve it - this is not a guaranteed solution though. The Xbox 360 has a bad track record for being able to play certain popular video codecs.

The WMV container format generally contains Xbox 360 friendly codecs, but is not guaranteed to. [This is a great article](http://forum.teamxbox.com/showthread.php?t=558753) on Xbox 360 media compatibility.